# Como verificar datas que passaram da validade?

Tags: vba, listview, excel-vba, userform

Criei esta `Sub` para tratar os dados da minha `listview`. Porém, a primeira parte do meu If não está funcionando corretamente: `.ListViewEntradas.ListItems(i).ListSubItems(7) < Date`.

Gostaria de deixar em vermelho os registros que já tenham passado da previsão de pagamento - primeira condição - **e que** não tivessem sido realizados ainda

- segunda condição. Desta forma preciso que responda às duas condições.

O problema é que se eu coloco o sinal de *menor que* (**<**) ele considera que todos os registros da listview correspondem a condição. E quando coloco o sinal de *maior que* ele considera que nenhum corresponde.

```
Sub PassouDaPrevisao()

    Dim Colunas As Integer
    Dim Linhas As Integer
    
    'userform EntradasTeste
    With EntradasTeste
    
        Colunas = .ListViewEntradas.ColumnHeaders.Count
        Linhas = .ListViewEntradas.ListItems.Count
    
        For i = 1 To Linhas
        
            'se a data de previsão for mais antiga que a data atual & se estiver marcada como não realizada
            If .ListViewEntradas.ListItems(i).ListSubItems(7) < Date And .ListViewEntradas.ListItems(i).ListSubItems(8) <> "Realizado" Then
                
                .ListViewEntradas.ListItems(i).ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                
                For X = 1 To Colunas - 1
                
                    .ListViewEntradas.ListItems(i).ListSubItems(X).ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                                    
                Next
                
            End If
        
        Next
    
    End With

End Sub
```

Qual o problema com minha lógica? E como posso resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver alterando a primeira condição com o seguinte código:

`CDate(.ListViewEntradas.ListItems(i).ListSubItems(7)) < Date`.